# unwanted characters from Oracle database and text files

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I have come across a SSIS loading issue where one particular column sometimes produces some unwanted character which i'm not aware of and the loading of data into SQL server fails. Now this data comes from a ORACLE database. Data is extracted from oracle database in a normal text format on Solaris platform. This is then brought across to a windows sql server platform for loading into SQL server db.

please find attached image showing the issue highlighted in yellow:

[image: UNWANTED CHARACTER]

Is there any possibility of escaping this character from the oracle database when extracting or escaping during loading into SQL Server database via SSIS package?

Comment: It would be best idea to sort out data at source level in OLEDB by using replace function. If this is not possible use Derived column task with expressions before loading into SQL

Comment: @BHouse how would I use the derived column tasks. What expressions could be to replace this unwanted character in the derived column?